# java: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?'

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i want to search a value in my data base and return it i made this function but it returns always 0 the result set doesn"t respond

here is the function:

```
public int getNat() throws Exception{ 
    String query = "SELECT code_nat FROM nationalite WHERE nationalite=? ";
       try ( PreparedStatement stat = cnx.prepareStatement(query) ) {

          stat.setString(1, (String)cmbNat.getSelectedItem());
          rslt = stat.executeQuery(query);
          return rslt.getInt(1);

       }catch(SQLException ex){
              ex.printStackTrace();
              return 0; 
       }
}
```

and here is the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
rslt = stat.executeQuery(query);
```

to

```
rslt = stat.executeQuery();
```

When using a `PreparedStatement`, you don't pass the SQL query to `executeQuery`, since the prepared statement already contains the SQL statement and the parameters you passed to it.

In addition, you must call `rslt.next()` before accessing the `ResultSet`.

To summarize :

```
stat.setString(1, (String)cmbNat.getSelectedItem());
rslt = stat.executeQuery();
Integer foo = null;
if (rslt.next())
    foo = rslt.getObject("foo") != null ? rslt.getInt("foo") : null;
return foo;
```

Comment: it was like that and it doesn't work so i change it, it still doesn't work

Comment: it gave me other error " Before start of result set "

Comment: @HindDev You are missing a call to `rslt.next()`.

Comment: thanks a lot it works i thaught i need it just if i have a lot of fields to return

Comment: @HindDev ResultSet after query execution has data pointer at 0. You have to move to next row from the query by `.next()` method. Also try using `.isBeforeFirst()` and `isAfterLast()` methods of `ResultSet`. They tells you if `ResultSet` contains any row. Using ony `next()` may cause some Exceptions if it is used on empty `ResultSet`

Comment: thank you a lot, I'll learn more about that, it's my first java application